# How to check if sessions are on

Tags: php, session

What is the easiest way in PHP to determine whether or not sessions are enabled in the php.ini file for the server. I am looking to make a pre-installation check for my PHP app and just need something to check this.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I check if I can even use `$_SESSION`"?

Comment: @Matt Yes. But I guess if I just set a session and then check if its active that would tell me the same thing no?

Comment: I think the right answer is to use ini_get to check php.ini settings however is there any one ini setting that enables/disables sessions?

Comment: @Aknosis that would be a valid solution except there is no "switch" in php.ini file...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!extension_loaded('session')) {
    die('You must enable PHP session support for the system to work.');
}
```

Comment: That's more like what I ideally wanted. I didn't realize you can test for extensions like that. That's going to reduce alot of my code. Alot. Thanks :)

Comment: Cheers, yeah after seeing you were doing a pre-check i thought that might be more along the lines of what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I think thats going to take away a couple hundred lines of code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a quick script:

```
<?php

// page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_index'] = "IT WORKED!";
```

Then, on another page:

```
<?php
// page2.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['my_index'];

//output: IT WORKED
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! function_exists('session_start')) die;
```